# The loop does not find all matches

Tags: javascript, node.js

I am writing a log parser that looks for matches from the config in the log and displays me everything it finds between the beginString and the endString. I pass the log file as an argument when running the script. The problem is that the script displays all matches and does not filter by the keyword `error cs`, although it should. I am a beginner and it is difficult for me to understand what the problem is.

```
const fs = require('fs');

let srcFile = process.argv[2];

const rules = JSON.parse(fs.readFileSync('./searchConfig.json'));

function check(inputFile) {
    
    var result = '';

    rules.forEach(rule => {
        console.log(rule.label)

        var file = fs.readFileSync(inputFile, 'utf8');
        var startIndex = file.indexOf(rule.beginString);
        var res = '';
        while(startIndex > -1) {
        //get index after beginString
            let start = startIndex + rule.beginString.length;
            // get index before endString
            let end = file.indexOf(rule.endString, start);
            res += file.slice(start, end);
            // get the text between
            res = file.slice(start, end);
            // set startIndex to next index of beginString
            // if not found the startIndex value will be -1 so end of the while loop
            startIndex = file.indexOf(rule.beginString, end + rule.endString.length);
        }
        const textByLine = res.split("\n")
        textByLine.forEach( line => {
            if (line.match(/error CS/gi)) {
                result = result+line;
            }
        })

        if(res){
            console.log(res);
            return res
        }else if(result) {
            console.log(result);
            return result
        }

    })
}
var data = check(srcFile);

console.log(data);

Config.json
[
  {
    "label": "Check Gradle Errors...",
    "beginString": "DisplayProgressbar: Building Gradle project",
    "endString": "BUILD FAILED"
  },
  {
    "label": "Check Unity Errors...",
    "beginString": "-----CompilerOutput:-stderr----------",
    "endString": "-----EndCompilerOutput---------------"
  },
  {
    "label": "Check ExecuteMethod Errors...",
    "beginString": "Aborting batchmode due to failure:",
    "endString": "Argument was -executeMethod"
  }
]

 logfile.txt
 DisplayProgressbar: Building Gradle project
 test1

 BUILD FAILED

 -----CompilerOutput:-stderr----------
 error CS 123
 456 error CS
 -----EndCompilerOutput---------------

 -----CompilerOutput:-stderr----------
 789 error CS
 warning
 warning
 -----EndCompilerOutput---------------

 Aborting batchmode due to failure:
 test4
 Argument was -executeMethod
```

Comment: That is because you're overwriting the previous matches `res = file.slice(start, end);`, you can define `res` just before the `while` loop and add the new match on top of the previous ones `res += file.slice(start, end);`

Comment: @Titus Thanks, after these changes I get all test results. But I also have a variable var `result = ''` that looks for `error CS` words in the variable `var res = ''`. If instead of  word `test2` I put, an error words such as `error CS`, then the output will stop there, the rest of the matches will not be found.

Comment: It doesn't seem necessary to read the file again for every rule, either. You're not making any changes to the `file` variable, you can re-use it for all rules.